# .htaccess (removing index.php ) not working as explained in user guide

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

i have started learning codeigniter a week back from now, i am  relatively new at it and still finding my ways through mvc pattern and Codeigniter

the issue i am facing is quite strange and em not sure what i am doing it to cause such a flow
i am followig this tutorial http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html
and was **trying to remove index.php from my site i.e localhost/Example.com/index.php**

So the problem is i have put my **.htaccess** file at the **webroot**  which is my **Example.com folder** i just copy pasted thebelow code from the userguide and put it my .htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

and i have remove index.php from a config file as well

**so now whenever i try to access localhost/example.com it throws me back to localhost directory**

i don't know what is causing such flow

can any one help me thanks i really like to know what is happening and what i am  doing wrong

i am using Wamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# remove index.php (external redirect)
# if /index.php is part of original request to web server
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
# grab text before index.php in $1 and do an external redirect to $1
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ $1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

# internal rewrite for CI front controller
# if request is not for a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# if request is not for a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# if request is not for one of these listed files
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
# internally rewrite to index.php/<request-uri>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

- `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: that doesn't work it still takes me back to localhost directory

Comment: Ok try edited code now. Is this .htaccess placed in DOCUMENT_ROOT or in a subfolder?

Comment: http://i40.tinypic.com/2w3pdhc.png... i think i have placed it in a right directory ..did i?

Comment: woaah . your edited code works thanks man . but its not picking up my stylesheet also placed in a webroot baseurl ="http://localhost/Example.com"

Comment: For css, js etc just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: that is how i was linking my css before 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>public.css">  in my header file

Comment: Can you see from page's HTML source what you get it there.

Comment: My Page source this 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/Example.com/public.css">
And still its not loading stylesheet

Comment: you are one genius guys Thanks millions you just made it work

Comment: i wish you can explain me those rules ,i don't want to be some dumb  programmer who just uses things without knowing the logic behind so if you have some kind of tutorial or even here if you can help i will be so helpful i really wanted to know what those rules mean...

Comment: Yes sure I will add my explanation/comments and reference link in the answer.

Comment: Thanks alot thank so much :) waiting for your update :) Thanks again

Comment: Thanks its alot to take in about htaccess and regular Expression but surely with time i will figure it out thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `RewriteBase /example.com` at the top of your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: that doesn't work it still takes me back to localhost directory

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn on the rewrite_module in Apache?

Comment: This line is un commented in httpd.confg 
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so